# Let every class of one group have it's own Log4j2 logging environment

Tags: java, multithreading, logging, log4j2

My program, behind it's main functionality, contains demon background threads that operate independently and most of the time are idle. If something goes wrong, the threads fail silently (they show a GUI warning, terminate, but program continues). As these threads operate on different context than the main application, it would be nice if every one of them could have their own log file. All threads are running a runnable which is some instance of my `Robot` class.

The `Robot` class defines `setLogger` and `getLogger` methods and uses given logger to log data. But as long as the logger configuration is same for the whole project, there's no way I could separate log for the demon thread.

Is there even a simple way to do it? Log messages from thread mixed up with main program log are useless.

Answer (score 0):

The RoutingAppender may do what you want. The way this works is, each thread sets a unique value in the Log4j2 ThreadContextMap, and the RoutingAppender will use this value to route to a separate log file. The Log4j2 FAQ page contains a [detailed example](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#separate_log_files).

Comment: Hello. Thank I think that is the way. But I'm kinda lost still. Can I kave a wildcard in `<Route key="special">`, such as `<Route key="Robot_[a-zA-Z\.\_]+">`? How do I select the rouuting file in the Java part of the project.